# Can Slack convert/substitute strings into another output?

Tags: slack

I feel like I've researched this to death, but I'm sure it must be possible (certainly considering the scope of Slack's customisation).

The general concept would be to allow a user to type in a string of a predetermined pattern, then that could be converted.

An example would be like the Giphy plugin, which takes `/giphy {$string}.gif` and dynamically alters the output by posting an image.

The intended output would be so you could type in something along the lines of `#12345` (or even `/foo 12345`) and this could produce a fully formatted string.

For example:
`/foo 12345`

is changed to output `http://foo.bar/p=12345`

I'm simultaneously skeptical that it can't be done, and that it can be done!

I'm hoping that someone has managed a solution that wouldn't pointlessly use hooks or bots (as generating a new message wouldn't really be very slick at all).

Answer (score 1):

You will need a [Slack app](https://api.slack.com/slack-apps) or at least an [internal integration](https://api.slack.com/internal-integrations).

Then just create a [slash command](https://api.slack.com/slash-commands), e.g. `/foo`, which will call your Slack app. Then in your Slack app you can just respond with a new message which will automatically overwrite the previous one (containing the `/foo xyz`) with whatever content you like. Or you can use additional API methods like [`chat.update`](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.update) to do the same.

Please also consider using [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slack-api) for further questions about programming with the Slack API.